# AS3 Textfield set width depending on height

Tags: actionscript-3, height, width, textfield

I have a problem with the textfield in AS3. I want to set the height of the textfield, and then have the width adjust to fit the content. So far I have not been able to find a solution on how to solve this.

I tried the autosize function, but that one keeps the width and adjusts the height.

In this picture you can see the problem: https://i.stack.imgur.com/srZce.png I set the height to be the same as the image, but when I use autosize it changes the height to fit the text. Instead I would like it to keep the height and adjust the width.

Comment: Set autosize so that the width adjust automatically, once the text is set and  the width is correct turn off autosize and set the height.

Answer (score 0):

This works :

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldAutoSize;

    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point
            var tf:TextField = new TextField();
            tf.text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor.";
            tf.border = true;
            tf.autoSize = TextFieldAutoSize.LEFT;
            stage.addChild(tf);
        }

    }

}
```

[image: Here is the result.]

Make sure your text field's wordWrap property is set to false.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work unfortunately. Since the width defaults to 100 that is the width of the text as well.